# NLTK book ch.2.8 #4, LazyCorpusLoader

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Read in the texts of the State of the Union addresses, using the state_union corpus reader. Count occurrences of men, women, and people in each document. What has happened to the usage of these words over time?

This comes from http://nltk.org/book/ch02.html

My problem: All the functions I know to count occurrences of words yield error messages.

Here's an example:

```
from nltk.corpus import state_union

len(state_union)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-cb4ef2bb9247> in <module>()
----> 1 len(state_union)

TypeError: object of type 'LazyCorpusLoader' has no len()

state = state_union

len(state)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error states, `state_union` has no `len()`. You can use `state_union.raw()` for the raw data, `state_union.words()` for the words and `state_union.sents` for sentences.

`len(state_union.words())` will give you the number of words.

Comment: Now I'm trying to solve the problem above, but I can't figure out how to get a count from each individual speech. Here are some things I've tried:

for fileid in titles:
    print fileid.count("men"), fileid.count("women"), fileid.count("people")

and 

for fileid in titles:
        print state_union.words().count("men")

Comment: Hint: `state_union.words(fileids=fid)` will give the words for a particular fid. And each fid contains one speech. You can try to use `nltk.ConditionalFreqDist` also (look it up).